# Vue justify-center doesn't center the cards

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

I want these two cards to be in the center but they appear in the top left corner. What am I missing?

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-layout justify-center>
      <v-card color="#132939" height="500" width="200"></v-card>
      <v-card color="#a3a4a4" height="500" width="800"> </v-card>
    </v-layout>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {};
</script>

<style></style>
```

Comment: It works fine with direct `<v-app>` parent. Please, check or post your parent components. [CodePen demo](https://codepen.io/betanet/pen/mdxqLJK)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most possible reason for this behaviour can be the limited width and height of the parent element (of v-layout), just like in the first example, where I made the div's width to be equal to two cards' width.

If the parent element has a width greater than two cards **justify-center** prop works as intended (second example - in this case, I set width to auto because it takes the width of the window).

If you want to make cards in the centre on a vertical axis you can use **align-center** prop but mostly you will have to set the height property for parents elements (third example).

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
});
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <template>
      <div style="width: 100px;">
        <v-layout justify-center align-center style="border: 1px solid black">
          <v-card color="#132939" height="50" width="20"></v-card>
          <v-card color="#a3a4a4" height="50" width="80"> </v-card>
        </v-layout>
      </div>
    </template>
    <template>
      <div style="width: auto;">
        <v-layout justify-center align-center style="border: 1px solid black">
          <v-card color="#132939" height="50" width="20"></v-card>
          <v-card color="#a3a4a4" height="50" width="80"> </v-card>
        </v-layout>
      </div>
    </template>
    <template>
      <div style="width: auto; height: 100%">
        <v-layout justify-center align-center style="border: 1px solid black; height: 100%">
          <v-card color="#132939" height="50" width="20"></v-card>
          <v-card color="#a3a4a4" height="50" width="80"> </v-card>
        </v-layout>
      </div>
    </template>
  </v-app>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```